# Неявное преобразование объектов почему работает по-разному?

Tags: javascript

В неявном преобразовании объектов приводятся к примитиву обе стороны, а потом происходит вычисление операции.
Если `{} + {} // NaN` , то есть обе стороны преобразуются к числу.
А в этом случае `[] + {} // "[object Object]"` , то есть правая часть преобразуется в строку, хотя по логике должно к числу, и выводить строку "NaN".
Почему так происходит?

Comment: Почитайте https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/347866/

Comment: _Если {} + {} // NaN_ - это смотря как проверять